# C# Ler Planilha excel

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, oledb

Olá, estou com 1 problema na leitura de uma Planilha excel,

```
ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() { GrupoFornecParceiro = rd["Grupo do Fornec./Parceiro+"].ToString() });
```

quando ele vai Add o valor da coluna "Grupo do Fornec./Parceiro+" ele vai para o catch, fiz a modificação manual na planilha e retirei o PONTO"." e funcionou, porém estou automatizando um processo, não me convém abrir a planilha e mudar o nome para retirar esse ponto, existe algum jeito de arrumar esse problema?

Já tentei criar uma `var a = @"Grupo do Fornec./Parceiro+"`
ficando assim

```
ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() { GrupoFornecParceiro = rd["Grupo do Fornec./Parceiro+"].ToString() });
```

Porém sem sucesso.

```
try
{
    conexao.Open();
    OleDbDataReader rd = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ACN = rd["ACN"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CEP = rd["CEP"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CepContatoDireto = rd["CEP do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Causa = rd["Causa"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CentroCusto = rd["Centro de Custo"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Cidade = rd["Cidade"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CidadeContatoDireto = rd["Cidade do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Correio = rd["Correio"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CorreioContatoDireto = rd["Correio do Contato Direto"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CreateImpactedAreafromCustomer = rd["Create Impacted Area from Customer's Location*"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CriadoTemplate = rd["Criado do Template"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CriadoEm = rd["Criado em"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CriadoPor = rd["Criado por*"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CriarSolicitacao = rd["Criar Solicitação"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CodigoPaisContato = rd["Código de País do Contato Direto"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CodigoAreaContato = rd["Código de Área do Contato Direto"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DataAlvo = rd["Data Alvo"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DataInformada = rd["Data Informada+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DataUltimaResolucao = rd["Data da Última Resolução"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DataFechamento = rd["Data de Fechamento"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DataResposta = rd["Data de Resposta+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DateTimeResolucao = rd["DateTime de Resolução Requerida"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DepartamentoContato = rd["Departamento do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Designado = rd["Designado+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DetalhesAdicionais = rd["Detalhes Adicionais de Localização"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {DetalhesLocalizacao = rd["Detalhes da Localização do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {EmailContato = rd["E-mail do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Empresa = rd["Empresa"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {EmpresaContato = rd["Empresa do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Empresas = rd["Empresa*+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {EsforcoExpresso = rd["Esforço Expresso em Minutos"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {EstadoProvincia = rd["Estado Província"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {EstadoContato = rd["Estado do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {EventMessage = rd["Event Message"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Externo = rd["Externo:"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Fabricante = rd["Fabricante"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {FabricanteR = rd["Fabricante (R)"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {FlagBroadcast = rd["Flag de Broadcast Enviado"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {FusoHorario = rd["Fuso Horário"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {FusoHorarioContato = rd["Fuso Horário do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {GenericCatego = rd["Generic Categorization Tier 2"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {GenericCatego2 = rd["Generic Categorization Tier 3"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {GrupoDesignado = rd["Grupo Designado*+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {GrupoProprietario = rd["Grupo Proprietário+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() { GrupoFornecParceiro = rd["Grupo do Fornec./Parceiro+"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {GrupoSite = rd["Grupo do Site"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {GrupoSiteContato = rd["Grupo do Site do Contato Direto"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {HostName = rd["Host Name"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IC = rd["IC+"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDAlerts = rd["ID Alerts 7,3,1"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDCorporativo = rd["ID Corporativo do Contato Direto"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDPessoaContato = rd["ID da Pessoa de Contato Direto"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDSolicitacao = rd["ID da Solicitação de Serviço"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDIncidente = rd["ID do Incidente*+"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDRegistro = rd["ID do Registro"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IDSiteContato = rd["ID do Site do Contato Direto"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ITComponent = rd["IT Component"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Impacto = rd["Impacto*"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {InicialNome = rd["Inicial do Nome do Meio do Contato Direto"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Interno = rd["Interno:"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {KickBackCount = rd["Kickback_Count"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {LastKickbackDate = rd["Last_Kickback_Date"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {LocalizacaoMesa = rd["Localização da Mesa"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {LocalizacaoMesaContato = rd["Localização da Mesa do Contato Direto"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ModeloVersao = rd["Modelo/Versão"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ModeloVersaoR = rd["Modelo/Versão (R)"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ModificadoEM = rd["Modificado em"].ToString()  });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ModificadoPor = rd["Modificado por"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {MetodoResolucao = rd["Método de Resolução"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NomeContatoDireto = rd["Nome do Contato Direto"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NomeFornecedor = rd["Nome do Fornecedor"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NomeMeio = rd["Nome do Meio"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NomeProdutoR = rd["Nome do Produto (R)+"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NomeProduto = rd["Nome do Produto+"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Nome = rd["Nome+"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Notas = rd["Notas"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NTicketFornecedor = rd["N° do Ticket do Fornecedor"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoOP1 = rd["Nível de Categorização Operacional 1+"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoOP2 = rd["Nível de Categorização Operacional 2"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoOP3 = rd["Nível de Categorização Operacional 3"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoProdutoReso1 = rd["Nível de Categorização de Produto da Resolução 1"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoProdutoReso2 = rd["Nível de Categorização de Produto da Resolução 2"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoProdutoReso3 = rd["Nível de Categorização de Produto da Resolução 3"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoReso1 = rd["Nível de Categorização de Resolução 1"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoReso2 = rd["Nível de Categorização de Resolução 2"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoReso3 = rd["Nível de Categorização de Resolução 3"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoProduto1 = rd["Nível de Categorização do Produto 1"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoProduto2 = rd["Nível de Categorização do Produto 2"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NivelCategorizacaoProduto3 = rd["Nível de Categorização do Produto 3"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {NumeroLocalContatoDireto = rd["Número Local do Contato Direto"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {OlaemEspera = rd["OLA em Espera"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {OrganizacaoContatoDireto = rd["Organização do Contato Direto"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {OrigemInformada = rd["Origem Informada"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {OrigemFechamento = rd["Origem do Fechamento"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {PapelGrupo = rd["Papel do Grupo de Suporte"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Pais = rd["País"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {PaisContatoDireto = rd["País do Contato Direto"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {PrioridadeSLM = rd["Prioridade do SLM"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Prioridade = rd["Prioridade*"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Proprietario = rd["Proprietário"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ProximaDataObjetivo = rd["Próxima Data Objetivo"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {RamalContato = rd["Ramal do Contato Direto"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Regiao = rd["Região"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {RegiaoContato = rd["Região do Contato Direto"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {RequerAprovacao = rd["Requer Aprovação"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {RequestID = rd["Request ID"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {RequestID0 = rd["Request ID(0)"].ToString(), });  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ResolucaoJustificativa = rd["Resolução/Justificativa"].ToString()});  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Resposta = rd["Resposta"].ToString() });  
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Rua = rd["Rua"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {RuaContatoDireto = rd["Rua do Contato Direto"].ToString() });
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {SLAEspera = rd["SLA em Espera"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {SLMTag = rd["SLM Tag"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ServerSerial = rd["ServerSerial"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Servico = rd["Serviço*+"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {SetResolve = rd["Set_Resolve"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {SiteCliente = rd["Site do Cliente"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {SiteContato = rd["Site do Contato"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {SobrenomeContato = rd["Sobrenome do Contato Direto"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Sobrenome = rd["Sobrenome+"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Source = rd["Source"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {StatusTempoReal = rd["Status em Tempo Real do SLM"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Status = rd["Status*"].ToString() });    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {StatusPPL = rd["Status-PPL"].ToString()});    
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {StatusReasonHidden = rd["Status_Reason_Hidden"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Sumario = rd["Sumário*"].ToString()});
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TelefoneCliente = rd["Telefone do Cliente*+"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TelefoneContato = rd["Telefone do Contato+"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TipoAssociacaoIncidente = rd["Tipo de Associação de Incidente"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TipoCliente = rd["Tipo de Cliente"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TipoClienteContatoDireto = rd["Tipo de Cliente(Contact Client Type)"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TipoIncidente = rd["Tipo de Incidente*"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {TipoTicket = rd["Tipo de Ticket"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {UnknownUser = rd["UnknownUser"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Urgencia = rd["Urgência*"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {IndiceSatisfacao = rd["Índice de Satisfação"].ToString()});   
        ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {UltimaDataConhecida = rd["Última Data Conhecida"].ToString()});   
    }
    if (ListaNomes.Count() > 0)
    {
        return ListaNomes;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Não Foi Possivel");
        return null;
}
```

Comment: editei e esta ai o código

Comment: :P Não precisava ser todo o código, você não consegue contornar com o `*`

Comment: você diz colocar "*" no lugar do "." ?

Comment: Acabei de tentar, sem sucesso, ele chega na linha e para, vai direto para o Catch, me retornando apenas Count = 44, tem que me retornar mais de 100

Comment: Entendi, explica melhor exatamente o que você está querendo fazer?

Comment: Tenho uma planilha do excel, retiro dados dela e envio para Banco de Dados, ele armazena os dados em uma classe chamada Entidades que contem uma string para cada coluna, assim que termina o while ele irá enviar para banco, porém meu problema está nesta faixa do código   'ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() { GrupoFornecParceiro = rd["Grupo do Fornec./Parceiro+"].ToString() });' , se eu vou na planilha manualmente e retiro esse PONTO ficando apenas "Grupo do Fornec/Parceiro+, ele pega valor desta coluna

Comment: Se você sabe a posição das colunas, seria mais fácil trabalhar com o índice ao invés do nome... você poderia inclusive criar um enum ou arquivo de configuração com esse mapeamento para quando o modelo for alterado no futuro, também dê uma olhada nesse post aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363492/retrieve-data-from-excel-contains-a-special-char-using-oledb-c-sharp

Comment: @GuilhermePalange, tente substituir o . por #

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Funcionou! exatamente como eu queria, obrigado!

Comment: Quem bom @GuilhermePalange! Assim que tiver um tempo vou colocar a resposta aqui explicando o motivo. Só queria antes ter certeza que daria certo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em linhas do **Excel** que são cabeçalhos o **ponto** (.) pode causar alguns problemas e ele é substituído pelo caractere de **cerquilha** (#).

Para corrigir você pode substituir o caractere **.** para **#**:

```
GrupoFornecParceiro = rd["Grupo do Fornec#/Parceiro+"].ToString()
```

Mas a melhor forma de você corrigir isso é mudar sua string de conexão do `OLEDB`. Você deve setar `HDR=No` e não terá problema com isso. **HDR** quer dizer **Headers**, então você basicamente estará definindo que não tem cabeçalhos.

> "HDR=Yes;" indica que a primeira linha possui nomes de colunas (cabeçalho), não
>    informações. “HDR=No;” indica o oposto.

```
string connectionString = 
                string.Format(
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";", 
                caminhoPlanilha);
```

Fiz alguns testes com caracteres especiais e o único caractere substituído foi o ponto (.) mesmo. Tentei encontrar uma fonte confiável para colocar como referência e assim já listar outros caracteres onde isso possa ocorrer, mas não encontrei. De qualquer forma deixarei no final algumas referências que podem ser uteis.

Apenas avalie se essa é a melhor forma de acessar suas colunas, como já comentaram na pergunta, talvez seja mais interessante utilizar o índice da coluna ao invés do nome:

```
ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {ACN = rd[1].ToString() });
ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CEP = rd[2].ToString() });
ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {CepContatoDireto = rd[3].ToString() });
ListaNomes.Add(new Entidades() {Causa = rd[4].ToString() });
```

Se o seu modelo não costuma mudar, talvez os índices sejam melhores nesse caso.

Caso você por algum motivo tenha que acessar pelo nome da coluna note que sempre que falhar ao buscar uma coluna pelo nome você poderá acessar o índice dela pra verificar o nome da mesma.

[Aqui você pode ver um exemplo no GitHub](https://github.com/Wurthma/RespostasSOpt/tree/master/Resposta_358164) que acessa colunas com vários caracteres especiais e imprime o nome delas utilizando o `HDR=Yes`. No mesmo exemplo tem a conexão com o `HDR=No` que corrige o problema.

**Referências:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20687817/5522115
2. https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/
3. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled

Comment: Rapaz, você me ajudou bastante, puro conhecimento oque acabou de me passar, fico muito grato pela sua ajuda e sua atenção, muito obrigado!